# Call Google Maps API key from services file

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

How can I add Google Maps API key to env file, then call it from services file like strip packages or any package? As you know Google Map API is JavaScript file like this.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**key=(call from services)&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

.env:

```
 GOOGLE_KEY=mygooglekey
```

services.php

```
  'googlekey' => [
    'ApiKey' => env('GOOGLE_KEY')
     ],
```

Comment: use server side if you don't want to show api key https://github.com/bradcornford/Googlmapper

Comment: I dont want to install googlmapper package so is there any other solution

Comment: only u can restrict  your api for some domain so if someone copy  ur api key they won't be able to use it . https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices

Comment: and from env you can get that value but it will be visible as it is in html tag

Comment: html page or blade view ? @Ash

Comment: I didn't get the solution here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calling config variable in your blade view like this

```
<script src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**key={{config('services.googlekey.ApiKey')}}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'" async defer></script>
```

or you can use env variable direct

```
<script src="'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**key={{env('GOOGLE_KEY')}}&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete'" async defer></script>
```